# .htaccess inside SVN

Tags: .htaccess, svn

In my localhost I have:

XAMPP
SVN FOLDER having joomla files

the problem:

The .htaccess file inside acgedu folder is not working. IT is not redirecting.

any thoughts? Last line Redirect is not working?

```
#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE 
# 
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems 
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already 
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in 
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to 
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work, 
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.acgedu.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.acgedu.com/$1 [R=301,L]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits 
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below 
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR] 
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR] 
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL 
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section 
# 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
Redirect statement
```

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account with your registered account. You should be able to edit your questions and leave comments on answers to your questions without issue now :)

Comment: Additionally, please consider adding the .htaccess file to your question (click the 'edit' link), you will get much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files work for the directory they're in and any subdirectories (unless overridden). You need to bump the .htaccess file back so it's directly in the "acgedu" folder.

Comment: I am sorry. .htaccess file is in acgedu folder only.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't post the actual redirect statement?